# Replace text in brackets gsub

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I would like to replace text inside of brackets, and that has a `colon` and a `u`.

For example, `Here is a link [u:person]!` would become `Here is a link <a href="/user/person">Person</a>!` I am not very experienced with regex, and I am having problems with `\1` and `$1`

Here is the regex that I am using now:

```
string.gsub(/\[(\w*).*?\]/, "<a href='/user/\1'>\1</a>")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a regex like this:

```
/\[u\:([\S]+)\]/
```

and replace it with:

```
<a href='/user/#{$1}'>#{$1}</a>
```

Here's a breakdown of what it the regex does:

- First, we have `\[`, which is just the literal `[` character
- Next, we have `u` and `\:`, which are the literal `u` and `:` character respectively
- Next, we have `([\S])`. The parentheses make a capturing group, which is what `#{$1}` will be filled in with in the replace part of the regex. `[\S]+` looks for all non-whitespace characters.
- Lastly, we have `\]`, which is just the literal `]` character.

Your code should look something like this:

```
string.gsub('/\[u\:([\S]+)\]/', '<a href='/user/#{$1}'>#{$1}</a>')
```

Here is a live test of the regex: https://regex101.com/r/vK0iO2

Answer (score 1):

I changed your regular expression to this, so that `person` is captured:

```
/\[\w*:(.*?)\]/
```

And then replaced it with this String:

```
"<a href=\"/user/#{$1}\">#{$1.capitalize}</a>"
```

You were close with `$1`, it just needs to be evaluated as Ruby (using String interpolation, inside a block):

```
string.gsub(/\[\w*:(.*?)\]/) { "<a href=\"/user/#{$1}\">#{$1.capitalize}</a>" }
```

Comment: This fails, as `$1` means the previous regex match.

Answer (score 1):

Make the regex `/\[\w*:(.*?)\]/` so that `person` can be captured instead of `u`. Then use a single quoted string so that `\1` isn't interpreted as `\x01`.

```
str = "Here is a link [u:person]!"
puts str.gsub(/\[\w*:(.*?)\]/, '<a href="/user/\1">\1</a>')
# => Here is a link <a href="/user/person">person</a>!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\[[^\]]*u:([^\]]*)\]
```

Try this.Replace by `<a href='/user/\1'>\1</a>`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/13